# Octopus deployment not picking up a process change

Tags: octopus-deploy, octopus

I encountered an error in one of our deployments today so i applied a fix to one of the processes and tried again, however the fix was not picked up.  I found i had to create a new release.  Is there anyway to force octopus to pick up a change if you try to run the current release again?

Comment: you can create a new release with the old packages, and the new release will pick up the changed process.

Answer (score 7):

That's a core concept in Octopus and its as design. Check the [Release Snapshots](https://octopus.com/docs/deployment-process/releases#snapshots) section of the documentation.

You can update the variables for an already-created release, but not the steps.